# Vagrant: how to configure multiple NICs within a Vagrantfile?

Tags: networking, vagrant

The official doc gives example only for 1 IP:

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
end
```

Googling around I could find only 1 example of Multiple IPs:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/hqtdOEjjlsw

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.define :web001 do |config|
    config.vm.box = "base"
    config.vm.forward_port("http", 5000, 8881)
    config.vm.forward_port("ssh", 22, 2222)
    config.vm.host_name = "web001.example.com"
    config.vm.network("33.33.33.10")
    config.vm.network("33.33.33.20", {:adapter=>2})
  end
end
```

but it doesn't work for me...

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Using Vagrant 1.6.1 and private networking with Virtualbox you can create multiple  private ips just by repeating the config.vm.network definition:

```
# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise64"

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.5"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.6"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.7"

end
```

Comment: and how do I specify adapter? I need only for second one, like in original question

Comment: You can specify the adapter as per the [vagrant doc](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html) and similarly as in tmatilai's answer below.  Heres an example I just tried:     

    `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
    config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.50.5"
    config.vm.network "public_network",  bridge: 'en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)'`

Answer (score 19):

That mailing list post is from long before Vagrant 1.1 and new configuration API, so the syntax is not compatible.

But you can just add as many `config.vm.network` calls as you want. A silly example:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.20"
  config.vm.network "public_network", type: "dhcp", bridge: "eth0"
end
```

Comment: `An IP is required for a private network.` in other words `dhcp` works only for public. Also its better to set up to which interface you want to bind: `config.vm.network "public_network", type: "dhcp", :bridge => "eth0"`

Comment: Thanks, I improved the example.

Comment: @sumid -- The [vagrant docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html) seem to disagree with you.  Unless there is some complication to do with combining `private_network` and `bridge` you were referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Confirming that a `Vagrantfile` with the following config statements:

```
$ grep '^[ ]\+config.vm.network' Vagrantfile
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.101"
  config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (Wireless)", auto_config: false
  config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en0: Wi-Fi (Wireless)", auto_config: false
```

Results in network interfaces as follows. As you can see there's interfaces internal to the IP that haven't been configured, but are present.

```
$ ip a l
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c0:42:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 86141sec preferred_lft 86141sec
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fec0:42d5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:91:77:71 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.101/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe91:7771/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:64:d4:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:a4:f8:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

If you attempt to add this to your `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", auto_config: false
```

You'll get this failure:

```
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/ipaddr.rb:479:in `initialize': address family must be specified (IPAddr::AddressFamilyError)
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.5/gems/vagrant-2.1.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:263:in `new'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.5/gems/vagrant-2.1.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:263:in `hostonly_config'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.5/gems/vagrant-2.1.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:91:in `block in call'
```

It would appear that `private_network` devices require an IP.